# Dynamic naming of objects in list

Tags: r, writexl

I'm using the write_xlsx function from the writexl package. I want to use the list function to dynamically name the tabs in the Excel files I am writing.

Code I have already tried:

```
Tab_Name = paste0(Input$IndicatorID_RC[i])
```

Pulls through the IndicatorID_RC from an input file which is the ID I want to use as the name of the tab in the output Excel file.

```
write_xlsx(list(Tab_Name = IndicatorData), path = paste0(Input$IndicatorID_RC[i],".xlsx"))
```

Create a list where Tab_Name is the name of the data frame IndicatorData and thus the name of the tab.

When I open the output Excel file, the tab name is Tab_Name and not IndicatorID_RC.

This code is on a loop starting with i = 1.

I'm sure there's a simple answer, any ideas?

Comment: `setNames(list(IndicatorData), Tab_Name)`?

Comment: Knew it would be simple... Thanks very much!